# How does this .forEach() method here work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, methods

I saw this code in the Codecademy forums and cannot figure out how it works. I understand that the code is looking for vowels in order to know whether to put a "an" or an "a" in the sentence, but I do not know how. Like why is he comparing the string at index 0 to a single letter? How does that even work? I feel like this is one of the easiest questions to answer but I am too new to figure it out. I also know that people appreciate it if you do your own research prior to asking a question, but I did not know how to do that with something as specific as this. If you have any tips on how I could learn better or figure stuff out in a better way then please let me know. Thank you!

```
const fruits = ['mango', 'papaya', 'pineapple', 'apple'];

fruits.forEach( fruit => {
  let indefiniteArticle = '';
  if (fruit[0] === 'a' || fruit[0] === 'e' || fruit[0] === 'i' || fruit[0] === 'o' || fruit[0] === 'u') {
    indefiniteArticle = 'an';
  } 
  //else if (fruit[0] === 'h'&& fruit[1] ===) { }
  else {
    indefiniteArticle = 'a';
  }
  console.log(`I want to eat ${indefiniteArticle} ${fruit}`);
});
```

Comment: `fruit[0]` corresponds to the first letter of each particular `fruit` (item of `fruits` array being picked at each round of `.forEach()`-loop)

Comment: The body of for each runs once for each element in the array. Each time it runs, `fruit` is an individual string, not the array. So `fruit[0]` is `'m'` the first time it runs.

Comment: ...and, by the way, i would do that like `if('aeoui'.includes(fruit[0]))`

Comment: `console.log( { fruit }, fruit[0] );` before the if statement could help you understand

Comment: Thank you guys, you really helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the first letter of the word with that_word[0] since strings are arrays of chars then compare with 'a' and 'an'. Cheers on your learning journey. You can try this way too.

```js
const fruits = ['mango', 'papaya', 'pineapple', 'apple'];
const vowels  = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

fruits.forEach( fruit => {
  let indefiniteArticle = '';
  indefiniteArticle = vowels.includes(fruit[0]) ? 'an' : 'a'
  console.log(`I want to eat ${indefiniteArticle} ${fruit}`);
});
```